# php login feature without a database, redirect error

Tags: php, html, css, redirect, authentication

I'm having some problems with my login feature using php with multiple users, I'm not using a database as this is a school assignment.

So the assignment is as follows "create an associative array with usernames as keys and encrypted passwords using password_hash. Once the user has logged in it shall print out the users name." We got a template that we should use, I will paste all the necessary code. So the problem I am having is, that when I try to log in as a user it keeps redirecting me so that I get the "too many redirects" error.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['password'],$_POST['username'])){

    include("pwd.php");
    include("user.php");

    $key = $_POST['username'];

    if(isset($user[$key])){

      $_SESSION['inloggad'] = true;    // Användaren har anget rätt uppgifter.
      $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];

    }
}


if(isset($_SESSION['inloggad'])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
else{
  echo "<h1>Vänligen logga in!</h1>";
}
?>
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" >
    <title>Sessioner</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="login.php">
        Username: <input type="username" name="username" size="20" /><br /> 
<br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Logga in" name="login"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

user.php

```
<?php
$user['admin'] = '$2y$10$9NyoNcqG9sh0KOrVnUXLr.KscgDy0L1S0klYXK67oxVBVsElbbGja';

$user['hank'] = '$2y$10$tQNcTINMIcotw0IczQ1nTuOVRIpbuqh5M/k.mLpz7ZiZl8q2WA0Cy';

$user['elias'] = '$2y$10$tQNcTINMIcotw0IczQ1nTuOVRIpbuqh5M/k.mLpz7ZiZl8q2WA0Cy';

?>
```

start.php

```
<h1>Välkommen</h1>
<?php
  include("login.php");

  if(isset($_POST['password'],$_POST['username'])){

    echo '<h1>' . $_POST['username'] . '</h1>';
  }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Länka in med PHP</title>
   <link href="css/styleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
      </header><!-- header -->

      <section id="leftColumn">
          <nav>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['inloggad'])){
              include("meny.php");
            }else{
              include("login.html");
            }


             ?>
          </nav>
          <aside>
            <?php include("aside.php"); ?>
          </aside>
      </section><!-- End leftColumn -->

      <main>
       <section>
        <!-- Lägg in innehållet här -->
        <?php
           $page = "start";
           if(isset($_GET['page']))
              $page = $_GET['page'];

              switch($page){
                 case 'blogg': include('blogg.php');
                         break;
                 case 'bilder': include('bilder.php');
                         break;
                 case 'kontakt': include('kontakt.php');
                         break;
                 case 'klotter': include('klotter.php');
                         break;
                 default: include('start.php');
            }
       ?>

       </section>
      </main><!-- End main -->

      <footer>
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
      </footer><!-- End footer -->
  </div><!-- End wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

styleSheet.css

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body{
    font-size: 100%;
}
p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Wrapper */
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
}
/* End wrapper */

/* Header */
header {
    text-align:center;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url("../bilder/bgImg.png");

    color: white;
}
header h1{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 1.9em;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
}

header time{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
/* End header */

nav{
    border-radius: 5px; /* CSS3 */  
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}
nav li{
    margin-top: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
nav li a{
  display:block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aa0000;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background-color:#FFC;
}
nav li a:hover, #leftColumn li a:active, #leftColumn li a:focus{
    background-color: gray;
    color: #ffffff;
}

aside {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;    /* Ger rundade hörn i Firefox */
    border-radius: 5px; /* CSS3 */  
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

aside p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

/* leftColumn */
#leftColumn {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    margin: 8px;
}

#leftColumn h1 {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
/* End leftColumn */
/* Main */
main {
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left:200px;
}
main h1{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
main h2{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
main section{
    float:right;
    width: 99%;
}

form label,a{
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
/* End content */
/* Footer */
footer {
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url("../bilder/bgImg.png");
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    clear:both;
}
footer #footerRight{
    float:right;
    padding: 5px;
}
footer #footerLeft{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
}
/* End footer */
```

the rest of the template is not really necessary for me to paste as it's just html code for the website, I just linked the css code if you want to check what the page looks like yourself. If you need any more information that I might have forgotten to write please notify me.

I know there's a problem with me using include("login.php") in the start.php, I just don't know how to solve it as I need the information submitted in the login form. The page controller is stating that start.php is the default page the template uses in the  section.

EDIT: sorry I was not clear about this part. it only happens once I enter the correct details, for example, admin:12345.

EDIT 2:
new start.php code

```
<?php
  include("login.php");

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){

    echo '<h1>Välkommen</h1>' . '<h1>' . $_SESSION['user'] . '</h1>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full login.php I'm using:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['password'], $_POST['username'])) {

    include("pwd.php");
    include("user.php");

    $key = $_POST['username'];

    if (isset($user[$key])) {
        $_SESSION['inloggad'] = true;    // Användaren har anget rätt uppgifter.
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    }


    if (isset($_SESSION['inloggad']) && ($_SESSION['inloggad'] === TRUE)) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "<h1>Vänligen logga in!</h1>";
    }
}
```

Comment: with the not true statement It instantly shows the the redirect error as before it only showed me it after I tried to log in.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but still getting the redirect error once I press login. and now even getting this error: "A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/MOMENT 4/upp4/login.php on line 2"

Comment: Gimme a few to load on my server

Comment: Think you have a caching problem.  Working fine on my server.  If you're using chrome turn on dev tools and disable cache.

Comment: Are you just running login.php or all of the code I pasted? because I disabled cache but still getting the session as well as the redirect error.

Comment: Running all of it.

Comment: I just tried it myself, but once I click login with the correct details, example, admin:12345 I still get the error. Sorry I might not have been clear about that part.

Comment: YEAH left that out I think,... mere details :)

Comment: it's the   include("login.php");  in start.php. that's causing your grief.... One sec.

Comment: Ye, sorry about that, updated the Question, any other solution you might have to this problem?

Comment: Try the updated code for login.php -- start.php was including login.php, login.php was causing the redirect everytime it was loaded. I moved the redirect into the if clause at the beginning of the code so it'll only redirect if it's an actual post and login attempt, otherwise the login.php loads and runs through silently.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the redirect problem, altought now it doesn't print the username that was logged in with.

Comment: You're assigning a value to $_SESSION['user'] but you don't use it anywhere that I see.

Comment: It just clicked now, you just reminded me about that and now using a different code in start.php instead, updated the question. Very helpfull, thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

In the `index.php` file there is a line `default: include('start.php');` that can cause this page to redirect to itself because file `start.php` includes file `login.php` which has `header("Location: index.php")`. The same problem would apply in case any other included file on this page lead to inclusion of `header("Location: index.php")`

Comment: How would you solve it then? because I want to show the username in the main page directly after logging in. That's why I need the form information sent to start.php.

Comment: How about just getting the username as a session variable `$_SESSION['user']` in `index.php` once it has been set as `$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];` in `login.php`?